guvcview displays still picture and not live stream
My question is about guvcvideo, hereinafter, “g.”   I used g. for the first time today, with Zoom.
The camera was producing a video of me, On the live meeting,g. displayed an old still picture of me.
g.found it and downloaded it all on its own and put in in the live feed. I could not get any response from g. to replace the picture with the live video.
System did not ask any questions or offer any choices. I have gone through the g. menus a couple of times and not found anything that seems relevant. Please advise, and recommend a manual or tutorial for g. joh joh
